# Install Genymotion 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: installation, genymotion, ubuntu-15.04

After installing the Ubuntu 15.04 [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) it failed to start with the following error.

```
genymotion: error while loading shared libraries: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I installed `libdouble-conversion1`, but it still failed to start with the following log output.

Command output:

```
genymotion
Logging activities to file: ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Log output:

```
Jan 9 13:40:10 [Genymotion] [Fatal] This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 5):

So after searching I found that the log entry was probably caused by missing libraries needed by the QT xcb plugin.

So I ran `ldd` against the `libqxcb.so` library.

```
cd genymotion/platforms
ldd libqxcb.so | grep "not found"
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-image.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => not found
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => not found
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => not found
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => not found
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

So there are a lot of libraries related to the QT xcb plugin that Genymotion assumes are installed. The `libQt*` libraries can be ignored because they are contained within the Genymotion install it's self.

After installing these libraries Genymotion started fine.

```
sudo aptitude install libdouble-conversion1 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-image0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-xkb1 libxkbcommon-x11-0
```

Comment: Worked for me on Debian Jessie

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me. I just did `sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5`. Now its perfect