# Install Genymotion 2.6.0 on Linux Mint 17

Tags: qt, genymotion

After installing the Ubuntu 15.04 version of Genymotion, I got the following command output:

```
Logging activities to file: ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Aborted
```

and the following log output:

```
Feb 23 17:34:41 [Genymotion] [Fatal] This application failed to start because it
could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, kms, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

After checking the similar thread [Install Genymotion 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 15.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688442/install-genymotion-2-6-0-on-ubuntu-15-04) , I went to the platforms folder and typed

```
ldd libqxcb.so
```

The output, however, was quite different:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9ee1e000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fbfa7d89000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fbfa7b79000)
libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007fbfa7974000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fbfa776c000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fbfa7550000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbfa734b000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fbfa7134000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fbfa6f2b000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fbfa6d0b000)
libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007fbfa6b06000)
libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007fbfa6901000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fbfa66fa000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fbfa64f3000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fbfa62f0000)
libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007fbfa60e2000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fbfa5ede000)
libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007fbfa5cdb000)
libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007fbfa5ac0000)
libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007fbfa58b8000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fbfa567e000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fbfa5441000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fbfa51b4000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fbfa4f35000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbfa4c2c000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fbfa4a22000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fbfa46ed000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fbfa409f000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbfa39f9000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fbfa3793000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbfa3574000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbfa3267000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbfa2f61000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbfa2b9b000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fbfa2989000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fbfa2784000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbfa8074000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fbfa257f000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fbfa2379000)
libxcb-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0 (0x00007fbfa2172000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fbfa1f47000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbfa1d2e000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fbfa1ae8000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbfa18aa000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fbfa1684000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fbfa142e000)
libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007fbfa1027000)
libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fbfa0cae000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbfa0aa5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbfa088e000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fbfa0667000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fbfa0463000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fbfa025d000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fbfa0058000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fbf9fe54000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fbf9fc51000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fbf9fa4f000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fbf9f848000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fbf9f63b000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fbf9f41e000)
libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fbf9dbb1000)
```

Then I followed this other thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/534415/cannot-mix-incompatible-qt-library and moved the Qt libs to a separate folder, accordingly:

```
mkdir qtlibs && mv *Qt*.so* qtlibs
```

After doing so,

```
./genymotion
```

returned this output:

```
./genymotion: symbol lookup error: ./genymotion: undefined symbol: _ZN8QSysInfo22currentCpuArchitectureEv
```

Comment: If I'm reading [this page](http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/compat_report/qt/5.3.2/5.4.0/f4f5f/abi_compat_report.html) correctly, this symbol was added in Qt 5.4.0. The most recent version of libqt5core5a I see available in the default repositories (on Mint 17.2) is 5.2.1. Possibly installing a more recent Qt version outside the repos will fix this?